# Calendar - "Connect to outlook" Issue (SP2013 foundation)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I am using SharePoint 2013 foundation. I used Internet explorer  11. The "Connect to Outlook" button is disabled. I tried using Chrome browser. It enables the button, but nothing happens on clicking the button.

I tried deactivating the "Minimal Download Strategy". But nothing happens on button click.

Didn't see any special log in the SharePoint log.

Any reason ?

Comment: Is your site added to the Trusted Sites or Intranet zone in Internet Explorer settings?

Comment: @RobertLindgren Yup, i have already added.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I came across an article ([Article Link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_ramblings/archive/2013/03/21/can-t-connect-to-outlook-in-sharepoint-2013-just-hit-f5.aspx)) where folks discussed that Exchange server needs to be present. In my virtual environment network the Exchange server was not present. Tested the behaviour in an intranet where the Exchange server is available and the issue does not appear.